# Conditionally hide value in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web

I have this simple Razor Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Gestor.Models.PrecoExportacao>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LinhaUn)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Apelido)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PesoLiquido)
    </th>
...
</tr>
```

If the value of model.PesoLiquido is 0 I want it not to be show, but keep the space in the table. How do I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the space in the table"?

Comment: This view shows a table where model.PesoLiquido is a numeric element... I want, if it's zero to leave an empty space in the place, but keep the table format

Comment: You show the wrong code. This code creates the table header. You need to show the part where the actual table content rows are created

Answer (score 2):

The code for a complete display table for the data might look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Gestor.Models.PrecoExportacao>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LinhaUn)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Apelido)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PesoLiquido)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach(var m in Model)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.LinhaUn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.Descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.Apelido)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if(m.PesoLiquido != 0)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.PesoLiquido)
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: But what if u want to hide the table columns as well is their no way without the indivudal ifs

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if` statement;

```
<th>
    @if(model.PesoLiquido > 0)
    {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PesoLiquido)
    }
</th>
```

Another option is;

```
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PesoLiquido > 0 ? model.PesoLiquido : "")
</th>
```

Comment: Model actually is a list of objects, so that I don't have PesoLiquido... I can have things like Model.Single().... But not a specific instance of the object I'm into..

Comment: So, what do you think about how do you get the table header if you have a model as collection type ? Consider to modify the view model.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by putting your `Model` into a `foreach` loop and have an`if` statement check each model from the list. Here's how:

```
@model IEnumerable<Gestor.Models.PrecoExportacao>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LinhaUn)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Apelido)
        </th>
        foreach(var model in Model)
        {
            @if(model.PesoLiquido != 0)
            {
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PesoLiquido)
                </th>
            }
        }
    ...
    </tr>
```

Razor views allow you to use C# language logic to manage the view on the server before sending it to the client. That means you can use statements such as: `if`, `for`, `while`, `try`, `var foo = 420`...

Comment: Model actually is a list of objects, so that I don't have PesoLiquido... I can have things like Model.Single().... But not a specific instance of the object I'm into...

Comment: @SergioDiFiore you can use a `foreach` loop to go trough each model in the list and check if `model.PesoLiquido != 0`. I added it to my answer.